# Compare two strings inno setup

Tags: string, compare, inno-setup

I would like to check MD5 of a file with this code:

```
[Code]
var
  MD5Comp: string;

procedure ExitProcess(uExitCode:UINT);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  MD5Comp := '32297BCBF4D802298349D06AF5E28059';

  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin

   if not MD5Comp=GetMD5OfFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\cg.npa')) then
   begin
     MsgBox('A patched version detected. Setup will now exit.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
     ExitProcess(1);
   end;
  end;
end;
```

But I get a "Type Mismatch" error when comparing the two string, so I am assuming that this is not how you compare them.

**Edit:** I've tried    `if not CompareText(MD5Comp,GetMD5OfFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\cg.npa')))=0` but it never execute what's inside the if.

Comment: To your update, you would have to write `if CompareText(...) = 0 then` because 0 means equality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be an exception of the Pascal Script compiler. You were expecting an expression like this (assume `S1` and `S2` are `string` variables):

```
if not (S1 = S2) then
```

But the compiler treated it like this instead:

```
if (not S1) = S2 then
```

Well, I would personally expect a compiler error instead of runtime one here. At least you have simple way to workaround this issue if you explicitly enclose that comparison into parentheses like:

```
if not (MD5Comp = GetMD5OfFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\cg.npa'))) then
```

Or optionally write more literally:

```
if MD5Comp <> GetMD5OfFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\cg.npa')) then
```

Do note, that in this case the parentheses are not needed because with the `<>` operator it becomes a single boolean expression.

Comment: P.S. note that `GetMD5OfFile` returns lower case string.

Comment: You're welcome! P.P.S for that case sensitivity difference better use `CompareText` function that you found.